# How do I verify that my eclipse project is effectively using tycho

Tags: maven, maven-3, m2eclipse, m2e, tycho

I am transitioning to Maven-Tycho and was dealing with many errors. I seem to have gotten rid of all the errors but when I look into the pom.xml file I see maven-install-plugin, maven-compiler, maven-release plugin, etc and no mentions of tycho like I see in my tutorial. Did I do something wrong how do I make sure that my project is using maven-tycho not maven only. 
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTycho/article.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any changes can be made in the pom.xml tab. The Effective POM tab is read-only, it just shows what Maven constructs when it parses your project. It's composed of your POM and its (grand)parent POMs. The Effective POM does not exist on your filesystem per se, it's generated on-the-fly whenever your run a Maven build - hence why the view is "read-only". You can change to tycho-compiler by modifying the pom.xml file replace maven-compiler-plugin with tycho-compiler-plugin. Make sure you add tycho to your eclipse environment